# Using a bash glob in a Run Script build phase in Xcode

Tags: xcode, bash, shell, glob

I've got an Xcode project with a build phase that copies some files around. Say I want to copy all rtf files from [project directory]/foo/bar to [project directory]/bar/foo. I would use a command like this:

```
cp -v foo/bar/*.rtf bar/foo/
```

Executing this in Terminal does exactly what I expect: all rtf files in foo/bar are copied to bar/foo. But when building, I get a build error from cp:

```
Cp: foo/bar/*.rtf: No such file or directory
```

`cp` can't seem to find the files. It's as if bash isn't expanding the wildcard. I know I'm in the right directory when the script runs, because I've run `pwd` before `cp` and it gives what I expect. And I've set the Shell of the script phase to /bin/bash. What am I doing wrong? Can I not use globs in Run Script build phases? If so, why?

**Update:** I [found out](https://ksearch.wordpress.com/2010/09/23/wildcard-expansion-bash-shell/) that you can turn off globbing in bash like this:

```
set -o noglob
```

And turn it back on like this:

```
set +o noglob
```

And [see all bash options and their status](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_06.html) like this:

```
set -o
```

I tried using the latter in my Run Script phase and it shows that `noglob` is disabled. So `noglob` is not the issue here.

Comment: The immediate problem is that `foo/bar/*.rtf` *isn't* matching anything, so it is passed as a literal string to `cp`. This is either because the current working directory is not `[project directory]`, or because there are no RTF files in `foo/bar`.

Comment: @chepner I have verified that I am in the project directory as I expect (via pwd) and that there are RTF files in foo/bar. Executing the same command from the project directory in Terminal does what I expect.

Comment: @chepner I have also tried using a full path (~/Documents/Code/project/foo/bar/*.rtf). Same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the paths for the `cp` arguments inside double quotes without realizing it, and globbing doesn't work in quotes. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

The issue can be revealed by looking at the build script execution from the build log (press the icon on the right of the build script line) and you will see that Xcode runs the script as:

```
/bin/sh -c \"cp -v foo/bar/*.rtf bar/foo/\"
```

and **globbing doesn't work when enclosed in quotes or double-quotes**.

I normally write a script to do that kind of stuff and run that instead.  So create a `tools` folder, next to the `.xcodeproj`, and write the copy instructions in that script (`tools/copy_pdf_files.sh`):

```
#!/bin/sh
cp -v foo/bar/*.rtf bar/foo/
```

Make it executable from the command prompt:

```
cd /path/to/project
chmod +x tools/copy_pdf_files.sh
```

Then run that instead:

```
${PROJECT_DIR}/tools/copy_pdf_files.sh
```

Comment: That pattern isn't in quotes. As shown here, you just have the shell trying to run a command named `"cp`. If the quotes *weren't* escaped, it would be fine, since the entire string is passed to `sh` and parsed.

Comment: @chepner Yeah you might be right; it appears the OP has solved the issue, but his answer implies what he posted and what was configured are different.  So who knows.